# can I Show the result that comes after winning or losing game inside the canvas in a dialog box rather than usin "Alert"?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

[image]can I Show the result that comes after winning or losing game inside the canvas in a dialog box rather than using "Alert"?

```
          function collisionDetection() {
  for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
   for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    var b = bricks[c][r];
   if(b.status == 1) {
    if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
      dy = -dy;
      b.status = 0;
      score++;
      if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
        alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
        document.location.reload();
      }
    }
  }
   }
   }  
   }


function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawBricks();
drawBall();
drawPaddle();
drawScore();
drawLives();
 collisionDetection();

  if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
  dx = -dx;
  }
 if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
   dy = -dy;
 }
 else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
   if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
    dy = -dy;
   }
   else {
     lives--;
     if(!lives) {
     alert("GAME OVER");
     document.location.reload();
```

I Want to show the line"congratulations you won" and "You Lose" in the dialog box rather then in alert box.

Comment: please edit your post to correctly format your code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay multiple canvases on top of each other. The bottom one can contain the gameplay area, while the top one can contain messages. Here's a simple example:

```js
const gameCvs = document.getElementById('game');
const gameCtx = gameCvs.getContext('2d');
const dialogCvs = document.getElementById('dialog');
const dialogCtx = dialogCvs.getContext('2d');

function showDialog(message) {
  dialogCtx.clearRect(0, 0, dialogCvs.width, dialogCvs.height);
  dialogCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  dialogCtx.fillText(message, dialogCvs.width / 2, dialogCvs.height / 2);
}

// For demo purposes, click the gameplay canvas to "lose" the game
gameCvs.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  showDialog('GAME OVER');
  dialogCvs.removeAttribute('hidden');
});

// Click the dialog canvas to hide it
dialogCvs.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  dialogCvs.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
main {
  position: relative;
}

#game {
  background: #11a;
}

#dialog {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <canvas id="dialog" hidden></canvas>
</main>
```